# How to divide double faced mesh?

Tags: faces

I have a double faced object, inside and outside, and I want to separate/delete the inside faces. What's the best way to do it?

[image: double faced mesh]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to delete the faces then recreate them.

1. Using edge select in wireframe view you can easily select the edges connecting each end using box select <kbd>B</kbd>.
2. Delete edges <kbd>X</kbd> will remove the duplicate faces and leave the two ends.
3. Select both ends and bridge edge loops (in the specials menu <kbd>W</kbd>) will fill in the faces you want.

[image]